# capture form value and pre-fill field in other form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, field

Please see this page: http://www.ingeniusprep.com/testing-new-home-page/

This is a landing page, and I have a field where someone can type in their e-mail address.

When you click on the button, a popup appears. Now click on "Medical School."  See how a form appears?  It has a field for e-mail.

How do I make it so that the field for e-mail is automatically filled in with the e-mail that the person typed in on the landing page?

(Note: this is a Wordpress website and I think that if I just use query on the landing page, it is not carried over into the popup because wordpress sees the popup as a separate "page." Maybe I need to use PHP somehow?)

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!

Comment: No, you should be able to use javascript without any issue.  It's all the same page.

Comment: For the popup, I used the simp-popup plugin, which essentially creates a new "page" and then displays that page as a popup. So I don't think javascript would work....   Can you tell me how to write the javascript though? Maybe I'll try the javascript and maybe it will work after all.

Comment: Javascript runs in the client, and since it's all the same page to the client, you can use javascript to modify the value of the email field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the email field that's initially displayed and the email field in the medical school form use the same ID.  Fix that and something like this should work.

```
$("#landing-button").click(function(){

  email_value = $("#entry_1440270198").val();

  if ( email_value != "" ) {
        $("#med_school_email").val(email_value);
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that, but it doesn't work... I think the JQuery just isnt carrying over from the page to the popup..

Comment: It definitely is. To js it's all one page.

Comment: Nevermind - i just got it to work, using your code (slightly modified)! Thanks!!